# Unable to get date in the appropriate format in android

Tags: android, simpledateformat, gmt

I am obtaining the `Date` and converting into the `GMT` format. I am obtaining it in the form of `Thu Jul 24 06:55:56 GMT+05:30 2014`. I want the date to be displayed in the following form  `6/19/2014 12:28:44 PM`. Can anyone tell me step by step how to do it. I read the following document `http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html` but the format tends to remain the same even if I use `a` and `L`. I am posting the code below, please guide me.

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("LL/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
 dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("LL/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
 //Time in GMT
     try {
        dateFormatLocal.parse( dateFormatGmt.format(new Date()) );
        Log.i("gmt time",""+dateFormatLocal.parse( dateFormatGmt.format(new Date()) ));
        date_edittext.setText(""+dateFormatLocal.parse( dateFormatGmt.format(new Date()) ));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
```

say if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy  hh:mm a");
String date = format.format(Date.parse("Your date string"));


String strCurrentDate = "Wed, 18 Apr 2012 07:55:29 +0000";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z");
String currentDate = format.format(strCurrentDate);

format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a");
String date = format.format(Date.parse(currentDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your problem but look :

```
Date test = new Date();
test.setHours(10);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
System.out.println(sdf.format(test));
```

This displays **7/24/2014 10:13:01 AM**
If I change `setHours` to `test.setHours(22)` this displays **7/24/2014 10:13:01 PM**
Hope this helps.